# Problem installing ffmpeg 4 on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: apt, docker, ffmpeg

I have a Docker image with Ubuntu 18.04. This has, from the normal repo package, ffmpeg 3.4.6, but I would like to upgrade it to 4.x. I tried the "standard" way of `jonathonf`'s PPA, but I'm getting library version mismatch.

Here are the details:

```
FROM nvidia/cudagl:10.0-runtime-ubuntu18.04

RUN echo 'debconf debconf/frontend select Noninteractive' | debconf-set-selections

RUN apt-get update -y && \
    apt-get install -y apt-utils && \
    apt-get install -y curl x11-apps xserver-xorg libglu1-mesa-dev freeglut3-dev mesa-common-dev \
    libgtk2.0-0 libxmu-dev libxi-dev mesa-utils htop libgtk-3-dev libglfw3 vim \
    python zip unzip software-properties-common ffmpeg imagemagick python3.6-dev && \
    rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

+ some unrelated stuff (CUDA, python packages, etc.)
```

after which (when I log into a container, but it's the same if I do it in the Dockerfile) I do the bog standard:

```bsh
add-apt-repository ppa:jonathonf/ffmpeg-4
apt-get update
apt-get install ffmpeg
```

i.e. something I've done quite a few times before when setting up different machines.

However, instead of the usual `ffmpeg version 4.2 Copyright (c) 2000-2019 the FFmpeg developers` or similar, what I get when I run `ffmpeg` is this thing:

```
ffmpeg: relocation error: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libavfilter.so.7: symbol av_gcd_q version LIBAVUTIL_56 not defined in file libavutil.so.56 with link time reference
```

I googled that and it seems to be a library version mismatch. I tried uninstalling and reinstalling related libav packages, putting the ppa at the beginning of the Dockerfile (before anything substantial is installed), `apt upgrade`, `apt autoremove`, all sorts of combinations, but nothing seems to give me a workable binary.

I guess I could get a static build of ffmpeg and include that in my docker image, but I'd much prefer not doing that and just install 4.x from a ppa/repo package. How could I do that?

Answer (score -1):

Just install **ffmpeg** via **snap**:

```
sudo snap install ffmpeg
```

https://snapcraft.io/ffmpeg

```
snap search ffmpeg                                                             
Name                      Version             Publisher      Notes  Summary
ffmpeg                    4.3.1               snapcrafters   -      A complete solution to record, convert and stream audio and video.
```

https://github.com/snapcore/snapcraft/blob/master/docker/stable.Dockerfile

Comment: I remember trying that, but i don't think it worked with Docker...

Comment: https://github.com/snapcore/snapcraft/blob/master/docker/stable.Dockerfile